# Android SurfaceView flip everything as mirrored

Tags: android, surfaceview, flip, mirror

I have a surfaceview that i draw bitmaps on it. How can i make everything on  surfaceview mirrored like < | >

My seBitmap method is like,

```
if (bmp != null)
    {
        m_canvas = m_holder.lockCanvas(rect);
        if (m_canvas == null)
            return;
        m_paint = new Paint();

        m_canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, rect, m_paint);

        if (m_holder != null)
            m_holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(m_canvas);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to scale the bitmap by -1 so it will be flipped. For example:

```
m_canvas.scale(-1.0f, 1.0f, rect.width()/2, rect.height()/2);
m_canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, rect, m_paint);
```

Comment: This setBitmap method is only for bitmaps that gets from camera. But i draw  sth with my finger too. Is it effect this too ?

Comment: You can apply scale matrix to any kind of bitmap so it should work also. Please respond when you'll check it.

Comment: i checked, nothing happened. Is there any way to flip all surfaceview visible area ?

Comment: I checked in my app and indeed there should be also dimension params, I edited my answer: `m_canvas.scale(-1.0f, 1.0f, rect.width()/2, rect.height()/2);`